# Get positions that are not set in table

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table called positions and in that table there are 4 positions

[image]

> On my model function below if my layout table has a position set then
>   I am trying to be able to get the positions that are not set

Currently only **column_left** and **content_top** are set.

**Layouts table**

[image]

> **Question:** From the positions table how can I get the positions that are not set. It should be able to get **column_right** and **content_bottom**

```
public function getlayoutpositions($name) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('layouts');
    $this->db->where('name', $name);
    $positions = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($positions->result_array() as $layouts) {

        $this->db->select('position');
        $this->db->from('positions');
        $this->db->where('position !=', $layouts['position']);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
```

> Returns incorrect should only show column_right and content_bottom

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position] => column_right
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [position] => content_top
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [position] => content_bottom
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In think in below code you have done a small mistake:

```
foreach ($positions->result_array() as $layouts) {

        $this->db->select('position');
        $this->db->from('positions');
        $this->db->where('position !=', $layouts['position']);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

In above code, For loop iterates with all layout objects(rows) and gives you data in `$layouts`. You are checking only first `$layouts` object and finding it in POSITION table and returning the result.

You need to create a array for all positions retrieved from LAYOUT table. 
In For loop you should fill that array, means store the value  of `$layouts['position']` in that array.

So after the loop you will get an array of all positions present in the layout table.

Now after the For loop write your code:

```
 $this->db->select('position');
 $this->db->from('positions');
 $this->db->where_not_in('position', /* Pass your array here */ );
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result_array();
```

I think this help.

Comment: I got it working I posted model functions in answer with result thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

Got it working now

Controller functions

```
public function index() {
    $positions = $this->getpositions($this->getlayoutpositions($this->router->class));

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($positions);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Model functions

```
public function getpositions($positions = array()) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('positions');

    foreach ($positions as $position) {
        $this->db->where('position !=', $position['position']);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function getlayoutpositions($name) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('layouts');
    $this->db->where('name', $name);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Correct Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position_id] => 2
            [position] => column_right
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [position_id] => 4
            [position] => content_bottom
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query - it could simplify things there:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM positions LEFT OUTER JOIN layouts ON positions.position = layouts.position WHERE layouts.layout_id IS null');
```